# reuse Deployed libraries?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I have a contract using a library. when I deploy my contract. I see that 2 smart contracts will be created. 
are there any ways to reuse my library without recreating a new smart contract to the nets?
[image]

Comment: Are you deploying those contracts from truffle?

Comment: no, from remix-ide